# Is it possible to convert a zip file to binary file to load into BLOB

Tags: java, blob, zip, informatica

I have to upload a zip file into BLOB using informatica, for this task, I am using java transformation. Using the following code, I was able to upload all the flat files and retrieve them from the database table in correct format.

This code is not working for zip files. Can you please suggest me on how to convert a zip file into a binary file so that it can be inserted into BLOB?

```
byte bytes[] = null;
File f1 = new File(TARGETFILE);
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f1)) {
  try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read = -1;
    while ((read = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    FILE_CONTENT=bytes;
    FILE_SIZE=Double.toString(f1.length()/1024*1024);
  }
  catch(Exception e1) {
  }
}
catch (IOException exp) {
  exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please read the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to post code properly.

Comment: Next, what do you mean by "This code is not working"? What happens, exactly? It doesn't help that you're swallowing exceptions in your inner loop...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple version, just converts the data to a hex print. Using these parts you should be able to get to binary no problem. Just save the conversion to memory rather then print the string.

package test;

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\ltc1298-arduino-library-master.zip");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        try {
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\ltc1298-arduino-library-master.zip")));
            dataInputStream.readFully(bytes);    
            System.out.println(String.format(Arrays.toString(bytes)));
            for (byte b : bytes) {
                System.out.format("0x%x ", b);
            }
            dataInputStream.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try and let you know.